# Snowflake Parquet export with Array Columns

Tags: sql, parquet, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble with exporting tables that contains array columns to parquet in Snowflake. For example if column array1 contains a value [1,2,3,4]. When I export to parquet I am seeing the result as the following "array1":"[1,2,3,4]" instead I am expecting the result to be like "array1":[1,2,3,4]. Not sure why result is array is getting converted to string.

Below are the images illustrating the issues

Shows table containing array values [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBLem.png)

Table is getting exported to s3 as parquet and displaying the parquet values [Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfTj2.png)

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, the array data type is converted into string during export to Parquet. Did you find the soultion?